# Get a list of items from a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have this class

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

I can access its items using Category.objects.all() from my views.py.
I want to access these items inside my template, but obviously this doesn't work:

```
{% for category in Category.objects.all() %}
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I solve the issue with getting the items in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest explicitly passing in `Category.objects.all()` from the view. This will let you reuse the template irrespective of how you filter your categories.

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()
    ...

{% for category in all_categories %}
```

If you are reluctant to do this then pass `Category` as a template variable and then lose the `()` at the end of `all`:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    model_variable = Category
    ...

{% for category in model_variable.objects.all %}
```

Comment: Calling `Category.objects.all()` from within the view makes more sense, especially when you think that if you have many objects returned you'll eg. need a pagination which you have to generate in the view as well!

Comment: While I agree it makes more sense to call from within the view, I actually prefer to do all my pagination in the template, using django-pagination (http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/)